# Send To -> Email a Link appends "undefined" at the end

Tags: 2007

On one of our sites, whenever using the "Send To -> Email a Link" function, the resulting link in the mail app shows up as "http:\site\linktodoc.docundefined" with that extra "undefined" at the end. Can someone explain what might be the cause of this and how/where I can correct it?

This is using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTPPost action contains a variable/property/... that is 'undefined'. Evaluate your code that is 'send to' and check variable/link/ per each item.

I think it's something like this: 'http:\site\linktodoc.doc' + variableX 
Where variableX doesn't contain anything.